# UIWebView is blank and it's not loading an image from Resources 

Tags: objective-c, image, uiwebview

I'm using this code to display an image in an UIWebView:

```
-(void)showImageWithLoadRequest{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"accent" ofType:@"png"];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl];
    web.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [web loadRequest:imageRequest];
}
```

The problem is that when i open up the app in the simulator, it shows me a blank UIWebView, without any image.

Any ideas to solve that?
I need to load images from my Resources. And in my Resources i have 2 images localizations. It may be the problem?

**EDIT**

As Seamus suggested, now i'm using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"accent" ofType:@"png"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
```

but it still shows me a blank WebView. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do this use html.
uiwebview `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`

and you can set htmlSourceCode like:

```
htmlSourceCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body><img scr='file://%@'></body></html>",[img path]];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlSourceCode baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: So, i'm using the code: 
`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];`
But it still shows me a blank window! It's not loading the image. any idea?

Comment: @Pheel check accent.png is existed or not. check webview.frame if you don't use ib.